# get unique values from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get unique values from elasticsearch using this dsl query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "model",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that if I have two models i.e. `moto g` and `htc one`, I get four results, `moto`, `g`, `htc`, `one`. How can I configure it to return two results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the mapping of your `model` field to add a `not_analyzed` sub-field instead and run the aggregation on that sub-field instead, like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type -d '{
  "properties": {
    "model": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {                      <-- add this section
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Once your mapping is updated, you need to reindex your data and then you'll be able to run your aggregation like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "model.raw",          <--- use the new sub-field
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using logstash to send my logs to elasticsearch. When I used model.raw directly, it threw errors ---> `doc_count_error_upper_bound:0` and `sum_other_doc_count:0`. Does logstash not send raw fields? Or do I have to modify the query in some other format?

Comment: You can either modify the [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-manage_template) in the Logstash config in order to apply your own template with `manage_template => true` or use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) in ES. Whichever way suits you best.

Comment: The change in logstash filter didn't work for some unknown reason as no errors were thrown and I didn't want to create a new template in my elasticsearch. I ended up updating the mapping and re-indexing the data. But it worked! Thanks a ton!